# adb shell dumpsys display Logical Displays means

Tags: android

adb shell dumpsys display
It prints Display Devices: / Logical Displays:
Can someone please tell what these stands for. Is “Logical Displays:” is the android system max supported parameters?

Thanks,
Amarender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html) you can read:

> A logical display does not necessarily represent a particular physical display device such as the built-in screen or an external monitor. The contents of a logical display may be presented on one or more physical displays according to the devices that are currently attached and whether mirroring has been enabled.

Comment: So Logical display parameters are MAX values like resolution and dpi.  ex: logical display resolution is **1080 x 1920** but physical display device can be less or more but android can render **max 1080 x 1920** . Is my understanding is correct

Comment: i guess you're right. That's not very documented outhere and i troubled to find this doc, but i noticed many new apps with multiple physical displays, or with multiple windows in one display. That's gonna be the future:
http://siliconimage.challengepost.com/